# How to optimize this PostgreSQL query

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, explain

I have a question regarding PostgreSQL query speed optimizations.
I tried with Indexes and I speed up some queries, but for this one I don't know why it's still slow.
With this explain (https://explain.dalibo.com/plan/8ace3g496e6112f5), I see that the issues are on the Index Scan for User and Location, but I have indexes and it's still very slow.

I don't know why my tables or Indexes can't be fully in memory.

```
    Query Text: SELECT "mygreatapp"."User"."id", "mygreatapp"."User"."createdAt", "mygreatapp"."User"."updatedAt", "mygreatapp"."User"."lastLogin", "mygreatapp"."User"."signupCompleted", "mygreatapp"."User"."visible", "mygreatapp"."User"."deleted", "mygreatapp"."User"."pushNotificationsToken", "mygreatapp"."User"."email", "mygreatapp"."User"."password", "mygreatapp"."User"."facebookUserId", "mygreatapp"."User"."name", "mygreatapp"."User"."birthday", "mygreatapp"."User"."birthdayString", "mygreatapp"."User"."bmi", "mygreatapp"."User"."height", "mygreatapp"."User"."weight", "mygreatapp"."User"."children", "mygreatapp"."User"."locale", "mygreatapp"."User"."timeZone", "mygreatapp"."User"."newMatchNotification", "mygreatapp"."User"."messageNotification", "mygreatapp"."User"."suggestionNotification", "mygreatapp"."User"."likeScore", "mygreatapp"."User"."likeNotificationFrequency", "mygreatapp"."User"."matchNotificationFrequency", "mygreatapp"."User"."messageNotificationFrequency", "mygreatapp"."User"."moderated", "mygreatapp"."User"."moderationDate", "mygreatapp"."User"."moderatedBy", "mygreatapp"."User"."isGrazer", "mygreatapp"."User"."blockedUntil", "mygreatapp"."User"."blockedBy", "mygreatapp"."User"."gender", "mygreatapp"."User"."emailStatus", "mygreatapp"."User"."emailOptIn", "mygreatapp"."User"."authProvider", "mygreatapp"."User"."role", "mygreatapp"."User"."drinking", "mygreatapp"."User"."eyesColor", "mygreatapp"."User"."hairColor", "mygreatapp"."User"."studyLevel", "mygreatapp"."User"."smoking", "mygreatapp"."User"."ethnia", "mygreatapp"."User"."religion", "mygreatapp"."User"."maritalSituation", "mygreatapp"."User"."conjugalSituation", "mygreatapp"."User"."blocked", "mygreatapp"."User"."lastLocationId", "mygreatapp"."User"."hiddenUniverses", "mygreatapp"."User"."jwtVersion", "mygreatapp"."User"."ipAddress", "mygreatapp"."User"."ipAddressCountry", "mygreatapp"."User"."ipAddressInEurope", "mygreatapp"."User"."ipAddressScore", "mygreatapp"."User"."phoneOperator" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" WHERE ("mygreatapp"."User"."signupCompleted" = $1 AND "mygreatapp"."User"."visible" = $2 AND "mygreatapp"."User"."blocked" IS NULL AND "mygreatapp"."User"."deleted" = $3 AND "mygreatapp"."User"."id" <> $4 AND ("mygreatapp"."User"."id") NOT IN (SELECT "t0"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" AS "t0" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."Like" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."userId") = ("t0"."id") WHERE ("j0"."likedUserId" = $5 AND "j0"."status" = $6 AND "t0"."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND ("mygreatapp"."User"."id") NOT IN (SELECT "t0"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" AS "t0" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."Like" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."likedUserId") = ("t0"."id") WHERE ((("j0"."userId" = $7 AND "j0"."status" = $8) OR ("j0"."universe" = $9 AND "j0"."userId" = $10)) AND "t0"."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND ("mygreatapp"."User"."id") IN (SELECT "t0"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" AS "t0" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."UniverseOnUser" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."userId") = ("t0"."id") WHERE (("j0"."userId","j0"."universeId") IN (SELECT "t1"."userId", "t1"."universeId" FROM "mygreatapp"."UniverseOnUser" AS "t1" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."Universe" AS "j1" ON ("j1"."id") = ("t1"."universeId") WHERE ("j1"."id" = $11 AND "t1"."userId" IS NOT NULL AND "t1"."universeId" IS NOT NULL)) AND "j0"."relation" = $12 AND "t0"."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND "mygreatapp"."User"."gender" IN ($13,$14) AND "mygreatapp"."User"."religion" IN ($15,$16,$17,$18,$19,$20,$21,$22,$23) AND ("mygreatapp"."User"."id") NOT IN (SELECT "t0"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" AS "t0" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."LocationOnUser" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."userId") = ("t0"."id") WHERE ("j0"."exclude" = $24 AND ("j0"."id") IN (SELECT "t1"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."LocationOnUser" AS "t1" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."Bound" AS "j1" ON ("j1"."id") = ("t1"."boundId") WHERE ("j1"."maxLng" >= $25 AND "j1"."minLng" <= $26 AND "j1"."maxLat" >= $27 AND "j1"."minLat" <= $28 AND "t1"."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND "t0"."id" IS NOT NULL)) AND ("mygreatapp"."User"."id") IN (SELECT "t0"."id" FROM "mygreatapp"."User" AS "t0" INNER JOIN "mygreatapp"."Location" AS "j0" ON ("j0"."id") = ("t0"."lastLocationId") WHERE (((("j0"."latitude" <= $29 AND "j0"."latitude" >= $30) AND ("j0"."longitude" <= $31 AND "j0"."longitude" >= $32)) OR (("j0"."latitude" <= $33 AND "j0"."latitude" >= $34) AND ("j0"."longitude" <= $35 AND "j0"."longitude" >= $36)) OR (("j0"."latitude" <= $37 AND "j0"."latitude" >= $38) AND ("j0"."longitude" <= $39 AND "j0"."longitude" >= $40))) AND "t0"."id" IS NOT NULL))) ORDER BY "mygreatapp"."User"."id" ASC LIMIT $41 OFFSET $42
    Limit  (cost=6109.21..6109.24 rows=13 width=652) (actual time=482.978..482.993 rows=18 loops=1)
      ->  Sort  (cost=6109.21..6109.24 rows=13 width=652) (actual time=482.976..482.990 rows=18 loops=1)
            Sort Key: "User".id
            Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 36kB
            ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=1947.03..6108.97 rows=13 width=652) (actual time=80.857..482.921 rows=18 loops=1)
                  Join Filter: ("User".id = j0."userId")
                  ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=1946.16..4945.48 rows=231 width=679) (actual time=1.442..386.430 rows=1704 loops=1)
                        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "User"  (cost=1945.46..2700.02 rows=476 width=652) (actual time=1.353..7.950 rows=4281 loops=1)
                              Recheck Cond: ((blocked IS NULL) AND (gender = ANY ('{MALE,FEMALE}'::"Gender"[])) AND (religion = ANY ('{BUDDHIST,CATHOLIC,HINDU,JEW,MUSLIM,NONE,PROTESTANT,ORTHODOX,ORTHODOX}'::"Religion"[])))
                              Filter: ("signupCompleted" AND visible AND (NOT deleted) AND (id <> 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 1)) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 2)) AND (NOT (hashed SubPlan 3)))
                              Rows Removed by Filter: 56
                              Heap Blocks: exact=621
                              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "User.signupCompleted_visible_blocked_deleted_gender_religion_in"  (cost=0.00..129.45 rows=3809 width=0) (actual time=0.227..0.227 rows=4655 loops=1)
                                    Index Cond: (("signupCompleted" = true) AND (visible = true) AND (blocked IS NULL) AND (deleted = false) AND (gender = ANY ('{MALE,FEMALE}'::"Gender"[])) AND (religion = ANY ('{BUDDHIST,CATHOLIC,HINDU,JEW,MUSLIM,NONE,PROTESTANT,ORTHODOX,ORTHODOX}'::"Religion"[])))
                              SubPlan 1
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=25.28..37.31 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.178..0.610 rows=59 loops=1)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Like" j0_2  (cost=24.99..29.01 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.163..0.239 rows=59 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: (("likedUserId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (status = 'LIKED'::"LikeStatus"))
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=58
                                            ->  BitmapAnd  (cost=24.99..24.99 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.154..0.155 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Like.likedUserId_index"  (cost=0.00..4.71 rows=38 width=0) (actual time=0.014..0.014 rows=141 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: ("likedUserId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text)
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Like.status_universe_index"  (cost=0.00..20.04 rows=1549 width=0) (actual time=0.132..0.132 rows=1559 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (status = 'LIKED'::"LikeStatus")
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using "User.id_lastLogin_blocked_isGrazer_index" on "User" t0_2  (cost=0.29..8.30 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=59)
                                            Index Cond: ((id = j0_2."userId") AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                                            Heap Fetches: 59
                              SubPlan 2
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=102.16..1611.05 rows=168 width=27) (actual time=0.054..0.284 rows=33 loops=1)
                                      ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Like" j0_3  (cost=101.87..667.81 rows=168 width=26) (actual time=0.042..0.083 rows=33 loops=1)
                                            Recheck Cond: ((("userId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (status = 'LIKED'::"LikeStatus")) OR (("userId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (universe = 'vegan'::text)))
                                            Heap Blocks: exact=30
                                            ->  BitmapOr  (cost=101.87..101.87 rows=169 width=0) (actual time=0.035..0.036 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Like.userId_status_universe_index"  (cost=0.00..4.84 rows=42 width=0) (actual time=0.011..0.011 rows=24 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (("userId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (status = 'LIKED'::"LikeStatus"))
                                                  ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Like.userId_status_universe_index"  (cost=0.00..96.95 rows=127 width=0) (actual time=0.023..0.024 rows=9 loops=1)
                                                        Index Cond: (("userId" = 'ckki8m4y81jew0792sw40q81w'::text) AND (universe = 'vegan'::text))
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using "User_pkey" on "User" t0_3  (cost=0.29..5.61 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=1 loops=33)
                                            Index Cond: ((id = j0_3."likedUserId") AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                                            Heap Fetches: 33
                              SubPlan 3
                                ->  Nested Loop  (cost=74.27..167.09 rows=7 width=27) (actual time=0.103..0.106 rows=0 loops=1)
                                      ->  Nested Loop  (cost=73.99..143.13 rows=7 width=27) (actual time=0.103..0.105 rows=0 loops=1)
                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=73.70..75.32 rows=162 width=26) (actual time=0.102..0.105 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                  Group Key: t1_1.id
                                                  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 40kB
                                                  ->  Merge Join  (cost=28.97..73.30 rows=162 width=26) (actual time=0.100..0.101 rows=0 loops=1)
                                                        Merge Cond: (t1_1."boundId" = j1_1.id)
                                                        ->  Index Scan using "LocationOnUser.boundId_unique" on "LocationOnUser" t1_1  (cost=0.29..778.03 rows=15178 width=53) (actual time=0.025..0.057 rows=46 loops=1)
                                                              Filter: (id IS NOT NULL)
                                                        ->  Sort  (cost=28.68..28.71 rows=13 width=27) (actual time=0.027..0.028 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                              Sort Key: j1_1.id
                                                              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 25kB
                                                              ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on "Bound" j1_1  (cost=11.19..28.44 rows=13 width=27) (actual time=0.020..0.021 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                    Recheck Cond: (("maxLng" >= '5.531'::double precision) AND ("minLng" <= '5.531'::double precision) AND ("maxLat" >= '49.15'::double precision) AND ("minLat" <= '49.15'::double precision))
                                                                    Heap Blocks: exact=2
                                                                    ->  Bitmap Index Scan on "Bound.maxLng_minLng_maxLat_minLat_index"  (cost=0.00..11.19 rows=13 width=0) (actual time=0.017..0.017 rows=2 loops=1)
                                                                          Index Cond: (("maxLng" >= '5.531'::double precision) AND ("minLng" <= '5.531'::double precision) AND ("maxLat" >= '49.15'::double precision) AND ("minLat" <= '49.15'::double precision))
                                            ->  Index Scan using "LocationOnUser_pkey" on "LocationOnUser" j0_4  (cost=0.29..0.42 rows=1 width=53) (never executed)
                                                  Index Cond: (id = t1_1.id)
                                                  Filter: exclude
                                      ->  Index Only Scan using "User_pkey" on "User" t0_4  (cost=0.29..3.42 rows=1 width=27) (never executed)
                                            Index Cond: ((id = j0_4."userId") AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                                            Heap Fetches: 0
                        ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.70..4.71 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.088..0.088 rows=0 loops=4281)
                              ->  Index Scan using "User_pkey" on "User" t0_1  (cost=0.29..3.83 rows=1 width=53) (actual time=0.018..0.036 rows=1 loops=4281)
                                    Index Cond: ((id = "User".id) AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                              ->  Index Scan using "Location_pkey" on "Location" j0_1  (cost=0.41..0.88 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.043..0.043 rows=0 loops=4281)
                                    Index Cond: (id = t0_1."lastLocationId")
                                    Filter: (((latitude <= '48.91064321183747'::double precision) AND (latitude >= '45.31335678816254'::double precision) AND (longitude <= '3.257852869245691'::double precision) AND (longitude >= '-2.025852869245691'::double precision)) OR ((latitude <= '50.94464321183747'::double precision) AND (latitude >= '47.34735678816255'::double precision) AND (longitude <= '8.155450105467445'::double precision) AND (longitude >= '2.658549894532557'::double precision)) OR ((latitude <= '50.94864321183746'::double precision) AND (latitude >= '47.35135678816253'::double precision) AND (longitude <= '8.279671659522354'::double precision) AND (longitude >= '2.782328340477646'::double precision)))
                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 1
                  ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.86..5.02 rows=1 width=79) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=0 loops=1704)
                        Join Filter: (j0."userId" = t0.id)
                        ->  Nested Loop Semi Join  (cost=0.58..4.47 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.056..0.056 rows=0 loops=1704)
                              Join Filter: (j0."userId" = t1."userId")
                              ->  Index Scan using "UniverseOnUser.userId_index" on "UniverseOnUser" j0  (cost=0.29..1.59 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.050..0.050 rows=0 loops=1704)
                                    Index Cond: ("userId" = t0_1.id)
                                    Filter: ((relation = 'FRIENDSHIP'::"Relation") AND ("universeId" = 'cjzx66jhlh8gx0974trtqhkb4'::text))
                                    Rows Removed by Filter: 7
                              ->  Nested Loop  (cost=0.29..2.87 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.018..0.018 rows=1 loops=18)
                                    ->  Index Scan using "UniverseOnUser.userId_index" on "UniverseOnUser" t1  (cost=0.29..1.59 rows=1 width=52) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=1 loops=18)
                                          Index Cond: (("userId" = t0_1.id) AND ("userId" IS NOT NULL))
                                          Filter: (("universeId" IS NOT NULL) AND ("universeId" = 'cjzx66jhlh8gx0974trtqhkb4'::text))
                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 4
                                    ->  Seq Scan on "Universe" j1  (cost=0.00..1.26 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.004..0.004 rows=1 loops=18)
                                          Filter: (id = 'cjzx66jhlh8gx0974trtqhkb4'::text)
                                          Rows Removed by Filter: 6
                        ->  Index Only Scan using "User_pkey" on "User" t0  (cost=0.29..0.54 rows=1 width=27) (actual time=0.006..0.006 rows=1 loops=18)
                              Index Cond: ((id = t0_1.id) AND (id IS NOT NULL))
                              Heap Fetches: 18
```

Thanks a lot.

Regards

Comment: I would start with rewriting the entire query, to get rid of all the sub-selects. The table "mygreatapp"."User" is used in six different (sub-) queries, I'm not sure if that's the most efficient way. Because of all these sub-selects, the query planner is most likely making the wrong assumptions about the data. And since you didn't share the DDL for the tables involved, we can't help you with improving the indexes either.

Comment: "I don't know why my tables or Indexes can't be fully in memory.". How big is your memory? How big are your tables? How big are your indexes? Is it faster upon repeat execution?  What plan do you get off you add BUFFERS to your EXPLAIN, and make sure track_io_timing is turned on?

Comment: The time is spent on the inner side of a nested loop join, but the cause may the mis-estimate on the first scan of `"User"`. I agree that you should try to rewrite the query with fewer self-joins.

Answer (score 0):

Your request is very large, it will take time to review it in detail. I can just give you some recommendations.

1. It is recommended to use `CTE (with as)` to make your query readable and simple.
2. If there are duplicates between your subqueries, write them as (`with as materialized`).
3. If you have `OR` conditions in queries, use `UNION` instead of `OR`.
4. If you have queries that return large results in your subqueries after the `IN` command, then use `INNER JOIN` instead of `IN`. Apply the same logic to `NOT IN` if you can.
5. And lastly, of course, pay attention to the correct indexing of the fields you use in the conditions.